# Mat Menu Always Appears in Upper Left Corner of the Browser

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular 12.0.2 with Angular Material 12.2.11.  When I right click to open mat menu, the menu always appears in the upper left corner of the browser.  I want the menu to appear where the user right clicks (on items in a grid of data).

Partial of html-

```html
      <mat-drawer-content>
        <div style="height: 500px;">
          <mat-table [dataSource]="this.backlogservice.backlogIssues" class="mat-elevation-z8" cdkDropList #tablebacklog
            #listbacklog="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="this.backlogservice.backlogIssues" cdkDropList
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="this.getConnected()" style="cursor: move"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, null)" id="tablebacklog">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="task" style="width: 10%">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Task </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <mat-icon (click)="showTasks(element)" style="cursor: pointer; color: #F70000;">exit_to_app</mat-icon>
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="orderby" style="width: 10%">
              <mat-header-cell style="font-weight: bold;" *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index"> {{i}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="title" style="width: 40%">
              <mat-header-cell style="font-weight: bold;" *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
              <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [matMenuTriggerFor]="sendToMenu">
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, {content: element})">
                  {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
```

Component file-

```js
            export class BacklogComponent implements OnInit {
               @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) matMenuTrigger!: MatMenuTrigger;
               
              constructor(
                private dataSvc: DataService,
                private kc: KeycloakService,
                public backlogservice: BacklogService,
                public _issueService: IssuesService,
                private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
                public sprints: SprintService,
                public modalService: ModalService
              ) { 
                
              }   

          onRightClick(event: MouseEvent, item: any) { 
            // preventDefault avoids to show the visualization of the right-click menu of the browser 
            event.preventDefault(); 

            // we record the mouse position in our object 
            this.menuTopLeftPosition.x = event.pageX + 'px'; 
            this.menuTopLeftPosition.y = event.pageY + 'px'; 

            // pass object data to the menu
            this.matMenuTrigger.menuData = {item: item} 

            // open the menu 
            this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu(); 

            } 
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried to recreate this in stack blitz but you are missing to much. Can you create a stack blitz with your current code?